# Conditional formatting is either highlighting wrong cells or not highlighting correct cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

When I use the following formula to get True/False for an expiration date data on a separate column (blue) in the below image, Conditional Formatting works correctly: `=TODAY()>EDATE(I4,36)`

It highlights all the **True** cells which means the date in Column I4 has passed 3 year limit and expired.

When I use the same formula and Conditional Formatting on the actual column with dates, it either highlights the cells that do not have an expired date (False) or does not highlight the date that is expired (True)

[image]

Not sure if you can see the image. But the column that says Nuclear Gauge highlights some cells incorrectly in yellow, where as the data in the column to the right highlights cells correctly in red according to the formula I used.

Comment: Check that that range the rule is applied starts in row 4.

Comment: The cell reference should reference that top row of the Applies To: range.  If you are doing the full column then change the formula to: `=TODAY()>EDATE(I1,36)`

Comment: I had two blank rows before the table and the range was incorrect, I deleted the top rows and selected the entire column for the range and now it WORKS!!! Thank you!